# How to get values from nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
ng-repeat="question in questions"
{{$index+1}}
ng-repeat="option in  question.choiceBeanList"
{{questionObj.questionId}} --> Here I have to get both data's
```

My question is how to get data in the second ng-repeat like below for loop example given.

For example:

```
for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<=5;j++)
{
console.log(i+"_"+j)
}
}
```

Comment: Use `ng-init` as described here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ngInit` for this

```
<div ng-repeat="innerList in list" ng-init="outerIndex = $index">
  <div ng-repeat="value in innerList" ng-init="innerIndex = $index">
     <span class="example-init">list[ {{outerIndex}} ][ {{innerIndex}} ] = {{value}};</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

check the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get at the index, you can use `$parent.$index`

Json model

```
  $rootScope.makes = [
    {
      name: 'BMW',
      models: ['335i', 'M3', 'M4']
    },
    {
      name: 'Mercedes',
      models: ['C250', 'E350']
    }
  ];
```

Nested ng-repeats

```
<ul ng-repeat="make in makes">
  <li ng-repeat="model in make.models">
    ({{$parent.$index}},{{$index}}): {{make.name}} {{model}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ahrq94Ed3t1jJAkuQtDO)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions">
  <div ng-repeat="option in  question.choiceBeanList">
    {{questions.indexOf(question)}}   // To get the index value of FIRST ng-repeat
    {{$index}}  // To get the index value of current ng-repeat 
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps...!

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass outer ng-repeat data like this

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions">
   <div ng-repeat="option in question.choiceBeanList">
      {{$parent.$index+1}}_{{$index}}
   </div>
</div>
```